# In Kibana, I have fields that contains a question mark `?` not showing in metric field

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-6

In Kibana, I have fields that contains a question mark `?`. The goal is to create a filter that excludes all entries containing a question mark in the field. So, when i'm trying to create a metric under Aggregation with `Term` those fields which are in `?` mark are not visible there, Please help to understand to a newbie ..

Below is the `logstash.conf`  with the filters i'm using  along with screen shot i have attached, please suggest what mistake i'm doing and what can be done..

I have ELK version : 6.2.x

```
# cat logstash-syslog.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/*/messages.log" ]
    type => "syslog"
  }
  file {
    path => [ "/scratch/rsyslog/Aug/messages.log" ]
    type => "apic_logs"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp } %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => ["@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score", "path"]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
 }
}
  if [type] == "apic_logs" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{CISCOTIMESTAMP} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} (?<prog>[\w._/%-]+) %{SYSLOG5424SD:f1}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f2}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f3}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f4}%{SYSLOG5424SD:f5} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => ["@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score", "path"]
   }
 }
}
output {
        if [type] == "syslog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                manage_template => false
                index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "messages"
  }
 }
}

output {
        if [type] == "apic_logs" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "noida-elk:9200"
                manage_template => false
                index => "apic_logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                document_type => "messages"
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

[image: Availbale Fields]

Comment: I'd like to add the OpenSearch tag to this question - @Karn would that be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue!

Why do I see the symbol ? by fields in the Kibana Discover page
When you open the Discover page in Kibana, you might see a question mark ? by fields that are listed in the available fields section instead of the character t. When you reload the list of fields, the type of fields is analyzed, and the question mark ? is replaced by the character t.

Be sure to check Mark the box `include system indices` at the extreme right in the below screen shot.

[image]

Rearranging field columns in the table
You can rearrange the field columns in the table. Mouse over the header of the column you want to move, and click the Move column to the left button or the Move column to the right button.

Reloading the list of fields
Complete the following steps to reload the list of fields that are displayed in Kibana:

Select the Management page, then select Index Patterns to list the indexes that are available.

Select the index pattern for your space to see every field and the field's associated core type as recorded by Elasticsearch.

Click the Reload field list button Reload field list to reload the index pattern fields.

The list of fields is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are using kibana , make sure after re-creating the index you are refreshing it, speically when you add new fields to it. This refresh is available under management section of Kibana against each index pattern.

"?" - represents a column available , but not part of elastic index until you do a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me - take a look at this link though:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query

This did work, at least some of the time! Execute (ES/OpenSearch API sandbox in Console):

```
POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

or via curl

```bash
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&pretty"
```

Note! This did work for me (along with Index-Pattern re-creation) in AWS OpenSearch.